# Having issues getting an image to show from another file

Tags: html

I'm currently working on an assignment for school right now, and I'm trying to get an image to show up from another file.

Right now, I'm working on a page in my HTML folder, I want to get an image of a bird from my photos folder.

I typed all of the code correctly, I can't get the image to show. Both the HTML folder and the photos folder are in my Gallery project document/folder.

Here's some of the code I've already tried.

```
img src="/photos/bird.jpg"

img src="photos/bird.jpg"

img src="bird.jpg"

img src="gallery/photos/bird.jpg"
```

Again I have tried just about everything and it still won't show. I re-sized my images in Photoshop and I wonder if that messed something up. Any help would be great, thank you.

(PS. Yes, I am including the brackets, and all of the small details, i just didnt include it for the sake of time.)

EDIT: Not sure how much this really matters, but the photos folder is one level below my HTML folder. Also, my teacher wants me to keep my photos in certain folders, so I can NOT put the image in my html folder.

Comment: Can you include an screenshot of your folder/file structure?  This may be a relative path issue.

Comment: Any ideas on how I could get a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show us the full directory path for the html and the photo for an answer.

Heres an example though:

html: project/html/index.html

photo: project/photos/examplePhoto.jpg

If you want to include the listed photo on your index page the source in the image tag would be: src="../photos/examplePhoto.jpg".

The "../" is to go back one directory, placing you in the project folder in this situation. Look up "relative pathing" to gain a better understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Sorry, I read that last sentence wrong. I just need to know how to get into my photos folder and get the image I need. I've tried: photos/bird.jpg and that still doesnt work. I also tried, gallery/photos/bird.jpg. This is becoming increasingly frustrating and I'm really starting to hate this class. I know what relative directories/paths are, because I just used them correctly in my last project.

Comment: you need to either screen shot or copy down the paths(starting from the project directory) to both the html file and the photo for me to answer that question

Comment: Ok well, I can't find a screenshot program to use. So if you know of any way I can take a screenshot, please let me know. I'll try my best to copy down the paths, 
(1)HTML projects folder, the first folder I created on my desktop, all projects i make for this class goes in here
(2)Gallery sub-folder
Inside my gallery sub-folder, are three more sub-folders
(1)HTML folder, thats where I am currently working on bird.html
(2)Photos folder, I'm trying to get bird.jpg into bird.html
(3)thumbs folder, I have photos in here, but dont need to use them yet.

Comment: I just saw your update about photos being 1 level below html folder. In that case, it should be src="../../photos/bird.jpg". Also if you're on windows, search your computer for "snipping tool". It is pre-installed on windows and is great for screenshots.

Comment: I tried what you just said, and it still doesn't work. I'll make a new comment with snipping tool screenshots.

Comment: Okay, good. Also just so you know, you can get the path of a file by right clicking it and going to properties. There will be a location attribute with the path listed there. I also suggest making seperate directories for each project you make as it makes things much simpler

Comment: I can't upload my screenshots. Is there a way I can send you the screenshots through another platform? Like email?

Comment: You could put the images on imgur and send the link. OR you could simply copy the path from file properties which i mentioned in my last comment

Comment: assuming bird.html is in the html folder with no subfolders in between, it should be: src="../photos/bird.jpg".